# Pentaho multi table input multi table output

Tags: migration, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

**Question in regard of Pentaho Spoon (Data Integration):**
How can I transfer the input of multiple tables from one database to multiple tables in another database? Basically a 1:1 data migration with creating the tables automatically in the target database.

I basically want to multiply the following transfomation: [Picture of table transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMvv0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Copy Tables wizard, under the tools menu.

To use it, you will need to create a new transformation and define both database connections that you want to use.